# GlusterFS with auto scaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, google-cloud-platform, autoscaling, glusterfs

How would you go about setting up GlusterFS with auto scaling? 
Or any alternatives to keeping files in sync between multiple servers?

*I found this but it's from 4 years ago:
https://serverfault.com/questions/328303/amazon-autoscaling-and-glusterfs*

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative is to use a drive mapper that will mount an S3 bucket as a local volume.

Each server mounts the drive on launch, via a userdata script or similar.

See [S3fw FUSE-based file system backed by Amazon S3](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse)

and

[CloudBerry Drive Mount Amazon S3 Bucket as a Windows Virtual Drive](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/amazon-cloud-storage-online-hard-drive.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo, I've been looking into this and the same for google cloud storage.

Comment: Have you used this in production btw? How's the performance and stability?

Comment: Yes we use CloudBerry in production.  I was surprised by both its performance and stability.  Rock solid so far.

Comment: You can use Google Cloud Storage Fuse (gcsfuse) to mount buckets of Google Cloud Storage: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse